# Why values not assigned in IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I parse some data

```
var result = xml.Descendants("record").Select(x => new F130Account
    {
        Account = x.Descendants("Account").First().Value,
    });
```

Then I try to some update

```
foreach (var item in result)
    item.Quantity = 1;
```

After this I have `result.Sum(a => a.Quantity)` is zero... Why?

Comment: What is `F130Account` is it a class or struct ?

Comment: I think we're going to need a little more code (classes e.t.c) before we can begin to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your `result` collection is evaluated again each time you start enumerating it, so `Sum` runs on new set of `F130Account` objects, different then `foreach` loop. That's how LINQ and it's laziness works.

Initialize results to `List<F130Account>` first:

```
var result = xml.Descendants("record").Select(x => new F130Account
    {
        Account = x.Descendants("Account").First().Value,
    }).ToList();
```

And after that both `foreach` and `Sum` will run on the same collection of objects.